# Meteor accounts-base vs. accounts-ui and accounts-password

Tags: meteor

My app gets the username and password from the client, then uses them to log in to another site on the web and if successful, the app runs `Accounts.createUser({useranme and password});`
I do not use the ui provided by accounts-ui.

Do I need to leave accounts-ui and accounts-password installed? Are they required for some behind-the-scene magic? or Meteor stock Accounts package(s) is enough?
If I remove them, will I still be able to serve each client his/her own created documents? Sorry, I am very new to Meteor. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several questions in here, so I'll inline the answers.

> Do I need to leave accounts-ui installed?

No. You mentioned you have your own UI for account management.

> Do I need to leave accounts-password installed?

Yes. `accounts-password` provides you with `Accounts.createUser` which you mentioned you are using.

> If I remove them, will I still be able to serve each client his/her own created documents?

`accounts-base` gives you `Meteor.userId()`, `Meteor.user()`, etc. You'll need those to publish per-user documents. But again, you'll need to keep `accounts-password` as mentioned above.